# How to convert a string with character codes above 127 to a byte array properly?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, ascii

I am retrieving ASCII strings encoded with code page 437 from another system which I need to transform to Unicode so they can be mixed with other Unicode strings.

This is what I am working with:

```
var asciiString = "\u0094"; // 94 corresponds represents 'ö' in code page 437.

var asciiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
var unicodeEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

// This is what I attempted to do but it seems not to be able to support the eight bit. Characters using the eight bit are replaced with '?' (0x3F)
var asciiBytes = asciiEncoding.GetBytes(asciiString);

// This work-around does the job, but there must be built in functionality to do this?
//var asciiBytes = asciiString.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();

// This piece of code happliy converts the character correctly to unicode { 0x94 } => { 0xF6, 0x0 } .
var unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(asciiEncoding, unicodeEncoding, asciiBytes);
var unicodeString = unicodeEncoding.GetString(unicodeBytes); // I want this to be 'ö'.
```

What I am struggling with is that I cannot find a suitable method in the .NET framework to transform a string with character codes above 127 to a byte array. This seems strange since there are support there to transform a byte array with characters above 127 to Unicode strings.

So my question is, is there any built in method to do this conversion properly or is my work-around the proper way to do it?

Comment: "I am retrieving ASCII strings encoded with code page 437". If it's code-page 437, then it isn't ASCII, and vice-versa. ASCII is code page 20127.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference between ASCII and code pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var asciiString = "\u0094";
```

Whatever you name it, this will always be a [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) string. .NET only has Unicode strings.

> I am retrieving ASCII strings encoded with code page 437 from another system

Treat the incoming data as `byte[]`, not as `string`.

```
var asciiBytes = new byte[] { 0x94 }; // 94 corresponds represents 'ö' in code page 437.

var asciiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);    

var unicodeString = asciiEncoding.GetString(asciiBytes);
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. The incoming data in my case is really of the data type string (not my choice), so I  must first translate it to a byte array in order to process it, probably best to do it the way that I did.

Comment: @OskarSjöberg that... is contrary; your current approach is based on a false premise, that `"\u0094"` is in some way related to `ö` - which is simply incorrect.

Comment: \u0094 is from the sample data that I recive from the other system. I get a string like "Oskar Sj?berg" (? == 0x94) . So I just need to convert the string to a byte array and then use code as you suggested to make it translate the byte array to a string.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, the problem with enconding437 and Encoding.ASCII is that it's GetBytes method does not seem to support bytes with values over 127. So should I just cast each char to a byte?

Comment: @OskarSjöberg that suggests that you are reading the incoming data incorrectly, with the wrong encoding. If you start with a *string* with a 0x94 in it, and that represents the ö, then it sounds like the encoding is being used *in reverse* (which is not legal). Converting a string to a byte-array **is** encoding. It sounds to me like the real problem here is a step earlier, in the original decoding, I.e. where the string came from.

Comment: @Oskar indeed, ASCII is 0-127, but you are incorrect about Codepage 437 - that *does* support higher chars: I've given an example in my reply. The problem is, hex-94 is not the character you think it is.

Comment: @OskarSjöberg: The character `?` doesn't have the character code `0x94` it's `0x3f`; just a regular question mark. Your string no longer contains the original information as it has been decoded with the wrong encoding, so it's not possible to convert it in any way to get the information back. You need to change the decoding, not try to reverse the damage that has been done already.

Comment: @Guffa, I am also in same situation, system that is sending the data is a legacy system calling a COM+ application. a string in that system consist of single byte characters withing range of 0 to 255. same as Oskar, I also need to get the byte (8bit) array of string passed to my function and then convert each byte to unicode character representation of it.

Answer (score 4):

`\u0094` is *Unicode code-point* 0094, which is a **control character**; it is **not** `ö`. If you wanted `ö`, the correct string is

```
string s = "ö";
```

which is LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS, aka code-point 00F6.

So:

```
var s = "\u00F6"; // Identical to "ö"
```

Now we get our encoding:

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
var bytes = enc.GetBytes(s);
```

And we find that it is a single-byte decimal 148, which is hex 94 - i.e. what you were after.

The significance here is that in C# when you use the `"\uXXXX"` syntax, the XXXX is **always** referring to Unicode code-points, *not* the encoded value in some particular encoding.

Comment: My code was just an example. I retrieve a string from a webservice (out of my control) and i get strings that all are characters from the 437 code page. One example of this is \u0094. Which i need to transform to 'ö'.

Comment: @Oskar which confirms the error is upstream. There is no such thing as a .net string with characters from codepage X. All .net strings are always always utf-16 code points. You are running this conversion backwards. The web service should be fixed IMO

Comment: ... or the code doing the "retrive a string from" bit is where the error is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look earlier in the code. Once you have the data as a string, it has already been decoded. Any characters lost in that decoding is impossible to get back.

You need the input as bytes, so that you can use your encoding object for code page 437 to decode it into a string.

```
byte[] asciiData = new byte[] { 0x94 }; // character ö in codepage 437

Encoding asciiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);

string unicodeString = asciiEncoding.GetString(asciiData);

Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);
```

Output:

```
ö
```